# Does Bitrate on sound files refer to bit/s or byte/s?

Tags: audio-engineering

I'm trying to understand the bitrate calculation of a sound file(`wav - uncompressed`) which is showed in a mobile app. I've searched on the web and found out the bitrate calculation as below:

```
bitrate = sample_freq X number_of_channels X bit_depth
```

So if I have a `stereo` sound file with `48 KHz` sampling frequency and `16-bit` sampling depth, the result is: `48000 x 2 x 16 = 1,536,000 bit/second` which corresponds to `192000 byte/second`. But they represent it like `192 kb/s`.

But as I know `kb/s` means `kilobit/second` and not `kilobyte/second`. I also used online calculators and all of them show it as `kb/s`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your calcs look correct, the value stated by the app looks wrong. MP3 files are in the range of 320 kbps, and WAV files are way larger.

Answer (score 2):

what you are calculating is the uncompressed bitrate.

However, MP3 uses lossy compression, typically achieving final sizes of about 10% compared to the uncompressed file (for constant bitrates).

Therefore you can have the same sample rate, number of channels and bit depths and different MP3 bitrates. See an example matrix from the following [website](https://tritondigitalcommunity.force.com/s/article/Choosing-Audio-Bitrate-Settings)

[image]

Things get more complicated since you can also have constant and variable bitrates, but the idea is that what you calculated is the *uncompressed bitrate*.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm calculating the `uncompressed bitrate` because right now I'm using only `wav` files. But  I still don't understand; when you say `kbps` do you refer to `kilo bits per second` or to `kilo bytes per second`?

Comment: it should refer to bits per second. Bytes per second are used with a capital B so it would have been kB or kBps. It might be an mistyping specific to that app.

Comment: If it refers to bits per second, it means the calculation on the table and all of the wiki pages do not match. I think they refer to kbytes/second.

Comment: did you try with 44kHz to see what is the bitrate that the app gives you?

Comment: I can not try different settings on the app(ST BLE Sensor) it only has its own audio files and settings.